# Feature of database-level audit in SQL Server 2012 Express edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

Like in SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition, can we have database-level audit in SQL Server 2012 Express edition?

Can we have Audit Folder in Security Tab?

Comment: [All editions support "Basic Auditing" (see the docs)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.110).aspx) but whether it does what you want it to do I'm not sure. The presence of that folder in Object Explorer may be a different issue, though. Do you have the RTM version of Management Studio Express? What does Help | About say? When 2012 came out, SSMS Express was limited in functionality, but this went away starting with SP1. If this is the problem then download SP2 here (get SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe): https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43351

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but since it got bumped I will answer with some updated information.

While Express 2012 was limited to server level auditing (referred to as "basic auditing" in feature comparison documentation) and its RTM SSMS version was limited in GUI functionality for auditing, newer versions have removed both of those limits:

- The [newest 17.x versions of Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) are 100% compatible with SQL 2012 (and every subsequent version) and has no GUI-based limitation on auditing features (assuming they're supported by the SQL Server version it is connecting to).
- As of [SQL Server 2016 SP1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/sql-server-2016-service-pack-1-sp1-released/), "fine grained auditing", i.e. database level auditing, is available across all SQL Server editions.

The term "fine grained auditing" is strange in context of SQL Server, as it seems to only be used in feature comparison docs by Microsoft, but not in any other documentation.

Additionally, I have written a distilled comparison of [key features across different editions and versions of SQL Server](http://expressdb.io/sql-server-express-feature-comparison/), focusing on the perspective of Express.

Comment: Doesn't Oracle have FGA?

Comment: Yep! Clarified my sentence. I've mostly seen it used in reference to Oracle, so when its used for SQL Server its strange as it doesn't seem to be common verbiage outside of charts and marketing material.

Answer (score 0):

Basic auditing means a server level audit. if you want to use database level auditing you need the Enterprise Edition of SQL Server 2012.

I have tested to create a server level audit on a SQL 2012 Express instance, and you can but you need to script it and you can't use the GUI for that. I tried it with SSMS 2012 (not the express) and it simply does not a Audit folder under the Security tab when you connect to an Express instance.

HTH

Arthur